# Python Tkinter - shape adjustment

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

first of all, i am beginner with python/tkinter. What am I trying to do: I am making a little dashboard, I placed vector graphic (png) like a canvas so I don't have to make everything by programming.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1900, height=950, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='dashboard.png')
root.photo = photo
canvas.create_image(950,480,image=photo)
baterrytop=143
powertop=300

procentop = 100
def key(event):
    global baterrytop
    global procentop
    if event.char == event.keysym:
        if event.char == "w":
            if baterrytop > 143:
                baterrytop -= 1
                procentop += 0.0018
            ctverec = canvas.create_rectangle(1574,688,1732,baterrytop,fill="green2", width=0)
            procento = canvas.create_text(1653,420,text=procentop,font = "Arial 12")

        if event.char == "s":
            if baterrytop < 688:
                baterrytop +=1
                procentop -=0.0018
            ctverec1 = canvas.create_rectangle(1574,143,1732,baterrytop,fill="#e9afaf", width=0)
            procento = canvas.create_text(1653,420,text=procentop,font = "Arial 12")

    #label1.config(text=msg)
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
```

Basically, if i press 'w' or 's' a rectangle should grow or be smaller, problem is, everytime i press the key (or hold it) I am creating a new one: 
`ctverec = canvas.create_rectangle(1574,688,1732,baterrytop,fill="green2", width=0)`
I don't think it's a great idea. So i tried to find out, how to just adjust the already made rectangle, and I couldn't find anything working. Is there a way, how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create your rectangle outside the key event. By using

```
ctverec = canvas.create_rectangle(1574,688,1732,baterrytop,fill="green2", width=0)
```

To update its position or size you can update it's coordinates when a key event occurs by using

```
canvas.coords(ctverec, old_x0, old_y0, old_x1, baterrytop)
```